# How to set SQL dialect in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: sql, intellij-idea

I'm working with IntelliJ IDEA 2017. I want to set the SQL dialect for an SQL file.

After I created the file, there is a message at the top saying the SQL dialect for the file is not set. When I click on the "Change Dialect to.." link, it opens an SQL Dialects menu. On the right, there is a pulldown link to select the dialect, but the pull down menu is empty. I went into "Preferences > Languages and Frameworks > SQL Dialects" to try to add some, but that menu is also empty and I can't seem to modify any of the fields.

How do I add SQL dialects to IntelliJ IDEA, so I can select one for this file?

Below is a photo of the menu I get when I select "Change Dialect to..." in the SQL file:

[image]

Below is a photo of the menu I get from "Preferences > Languages and Frameworks > SQL Dialects". I can't edit any of the fields.

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors in [log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085)? Could you post it somewhere after restarting the IDE and opening sql dialects list in this dialog?

Comment: The only log I'm aware of is the Event log accessed via View > Tool Windows > Event Log. There are no errors in it. But there is a pulldown available on the message in the file that says the SQL dialect is not selected. If I click on the pulldown, the choices are: "Edit inspection path settings", "Fix all 'SQL dialect detection' problems", "Run inspection on", "Disable inspection", and "Suppress for file"

Comment: Do you use 3rd custom plugins? idea.log: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085 after IDE restart and reproducing.

Comment: I have not downloaded any plugins, I'm only using what came with IntelliJ.

Comment: I found the idea.log file. I cleared it out, started IntelliJ and tried to set the SQL dialect again. I then looked in the log file for anything related to SQL dialect. I found nothing. There are 7 java.util.zip.ZipExceptions, I'm not sure what they result from. If I clear the log while IntelliJ is running and try to set the dialect again, nothing is written to the log.

Comment: I have it set according to the Pim Hazebrock's answer. Nevertheless the jpa-ql editor on persistence view still errors 'Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set'. And I also did create a persistence.xml in src/main/resources/META-INF with having that property 'hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect' set as well.

Answer (score 28):

Please check if "**Database tools and SQL**" plugin is enabled.

`Settings` or `Preferences` > `Languages & Frameworks` > `SQL Dialects`

Here is how it looks in my IDE: (2018.2 EAP)

[image: SQL dialects]

Comment: Yes, I have the plugin and it is enables (it's checkbox is selected).