# Set SQL Dialect Injection on a String

Tags: python, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, how do you set or tag the SQL dialect being injected for an individual string literal? I frequently query multiple RDBMS databases (e.g., PostgreSQL, MySQL, MSSQL) within the same file and I'd like each to be properly inspected by IDEA. I found the comment incantation once before, however, I can't seem to find it again. E.g.,

```
# Mark as PostgreSQL.
psycopg2_cursor.execute("""
  -- PostgreSQL query...
""")

# Tag as MySQL.
pymysql_cursor.execute("""
  # MySQL query...
""")

# Tag as T-SQL.
pymssql_cursor.execute("""
  -- MSSQL query...
""")
```

NOTE: This is not a duplicate of [How to set sql dialect in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50711207/369450) because that deals with assigning the SQL dialect for a whole file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string can be marked as an injected language (e.g., a SQL dialect) using a [language injection comment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-language-injections.html#use-language-injection-comments). In Python, you can mark a variable or an argument as follows:

```
# language=PostgreSQL
psycopg2_query = """
  -- PostgreSQL query...
"""

pymssql_cursor.execute(
  # language=TSQL
  """
    -- MSSQL query...
  """
)
```